# How to create a comma separated string of the last five unique purchases by a customer in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery I need to fill a field with a string containing the last five unique products bought by a customer. I have previously used the `STRING_AGG` function but not both ordering and distinct and thats where I get a problem.
So I'm trying the following (which works if `DISTINCT` is removed):

```
SELECT  ps.customerID, STRING_AGG( DISTINCT ps.productId ORDER BY ps.orderDate DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS lastFiveProducts
FROM view.purchases  AS ps
WHERE ps.market = 'SE'
GROUP BY ps.customerID
limit 100
```

Where I would like the `STRING_AGG` to result in a string like: "23423,63764,62345,00787,91228"

Bigquery gives the error:

> "An aggregate function that has both DISTINCT and ORDER BY arguments can only ORDER BY expressions that are arguments to the function at [1:67]"

so these cannot be combined.

What other ways could this kind of field be constructed? A subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct` in a subquery -- using `group by`:

```
SELECT ps.customerID,
       STRING_AGG(ps.productId ORDER BY ps.last_orderDate DESC LIMIT 5 ) AS lastFiveProducts
FROM (SELECT ps.customerID, ps.productId, MAX(ps.orderDate) as last_orderDate
      FROM view.purchases ps
      WHERE ps.market = 'SE'
      GROUP BY ps.customerID
     ) ps
GROUP BY ps.customerID;
```

Actually, I would use window functions and put the limiting logic in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ps.customerID,
       STRING_AGG(ps.productId ORDER BY ps.last_orderDate DESC) AS lastFiveProducts
FROM (SELECT ps.customerID, ps.productId, MAX(ps.orderDate) as last_orderDate,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ps.customerID ORDER BY MAX(ps.orderDate)) as seqnum
      FROM view.purchases ps
      WHERE ps.market = 'SE'
      GROUP BY ps.customerID
     ) ps
WHERE seqnum <= 5
GROUP BY ps.customerID;
```

Admittedly, this is a bias because other databases do not support `LIMIT` in string aggregation functions.

Comment: This solved my problem! I tried both variants and where the first took about 20 seconds to run, the second I stopped when it passed 120 seconds, so I'll be using the first solution.

Comment: @EdwardHiscoke . . . My instincts on BigQuery are not always as good as they are on other databases.